# CA2000 warning on Class Level Object

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ca2000

I have an object that is declared at the class level which is giving CA2000 warning.  How can I get rid of the CA2000 warning from the code below?

```
public partial class someclass : Window
{
    System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog dlg = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog()
    {
        AddExtension = true,
        CheckFileExists = true,
        CheckPathExists = true,
        DefaultExt = "xsd",
        FileName = lastFileName,
        Filter = "XML Schema Definitions (*.xsd)|*.xsd|All Files (*.*)|*.*",
        InitialDirectory = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop),
        RestoreDirectory = true,
        Title = "Open an XML Schema Definition File"
    };
}
```

The warning is- Warning CA2000  In method 'SIMPathFinder.SIMPathFinder()', object 'new OpenFileDialog()' is not disposed along all exception paths. Call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'new OpenFileDialog()' before all references to it are out of scope.

Comment: Do you mean fix the cause of the warning? Or hide it so it doesn't show up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CA2000](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182289.aspx) says that instances of your class own a disposable object that should be disposed to free used (unmanaged) resources before the instance of your class gets out of scope.

A common pattern to do this is to implement the `IDisposable` interface and an `protected virtual Dispose` method:

```
public partial class someclass : Window, IDisposable // implement IDisposable
{
    // shortened for brevity
    System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog dlg = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
            dlg.Dispose(); // dispose the dialog
    }

    public void Dispose() // IDisposable implementation
    {
        Dispose(true);
        // tell the GC that there's no need for a finalizer call
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this); 

    }
}
```

Read more about the [Dispose-Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e.aspx)

---

As a side note: It seems your mixing WPF and Windows Forms. You inherit from `Window` (which I presume is `System.Windows.Window` as your question is tagged [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf)), but try to use a `System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog`.
To mix these two UI frameworks is not a good idea. Use [`Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: There is no need to implement finalizer (which you omited but I guess it's still there because of GC.SuppressFinalize(this)) when all you do is dispose child objects.